# Writing to .htaccess with php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to add lines to my .htaccess file using a simple php script. I know this is dangerous - it's for development, testing and learning, not for production.
I want to add lines of page redirects like this to .htaccess:

```
Redirect /url1.html https://exampleredirecturl.com/page1
Redirect /url2.html https://exampleredirecturl.com/page2
```

The script I'm using is this:

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" ){

        $text = trim($_POST['all_redirects']);
        if($text == ""){die("invalid input");}
        $textAr = explode("\n", $text);
        $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); 
        $file = fopen('.htaccess', 'a') or die('Fail to open .htaccess file');

        foreach ($textAr as $line) {
            echo $line."<br>";
            fwrite($file, $line);
        } 
        fwrite($file, "\n");
        fclose($file);

    }

?>


<form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea name="all_redirects" rows="35" cols="150"></textarea>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="" value="Save to htaccess">
</form>
```

The problem is that when I run the script and enter a list of redirect lines (as above) and save to htaccess, the resulting htaccess file appears OK when viewed in a
code editor, but doesn't work as expected, because there seems to be a problem with the line feeds. If I manually edit the file and hit enter after each line and save, then everything works fine. Any suggestions as to what is going on, and what should I do to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe worth taking a look at [PHP_EOL](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php), e.g. `echo $line.PHP_EOL;
    fwrite($file, $line.PHP_EOL);`

Comment: Yep - that worked - thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

OK - this is the answer - thank you to JustBaron who came up with the solution and Álvaro González who also looked at it for me:

```
  <?php

    if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" ){

        $text = trim($_POST['all_redirects']);
        if($text == ""){die("invalid input");}
        $textAr = explode("\n", $text);
        $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); 
        $file = fopen('.htaccess', 'a') or die('Fail to open .htaccess file');

        foreach ($textAr as $line) {
            echo $line.PHP_EOL;
            fwrite($file, $line.PHP_EOL);
        } 
        fwrite($file, "\n");
        fclose($file);

    }

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea name="all_redirects" rows="35" cols="150"></textarea>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="" value="Save to htaccess">
</form>
```

Comment: You can use `$line.PHP_EOL` or `$line . "\n"`. The EOL style was probably a red herring — you were not inserting any.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of Apache having preferences for any EOL style. But your script is not inserting line ends at all, just a trailing one at the end of the file:

```
foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    fwrite($file, $line);
} 
fwrite($file, "\n"); // <--- Just this one!
```

Perhap's you're assuming that `explode()` keeps the separator. It doesn't:

```
var_dump(explode("\n", "A\nB\nC\n"));
```

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

**Update:** I missed the "appears OK when viewed in a code editor" part. That might indicate that your input contains Windows EOLs ("\r\n") and you strip ("\n") so you end up with legacy MacOS style ("\r"). Perhaps Apache doesn't like *those*. :-?